# "Timer Toast" display lags then actual "Countdown Timer"

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-toast

I am showing time out seconds using `Toast` inside `Countdown Timer`, But I feel the display of `Toast` is actually lagging then the real time seconds, is there any better way to display message properly ?

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabling Task, Please wait : " + millisUntilFinished/1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congratulations!! Time out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is toast are added to a queue and executed one after another. Your ticks are quicker than the `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` which causes delay. You want to hold a reference to previous toast and cancel it before showing a new one.

```
Toast mToast = null;

CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if (mToast != null) mToast.cancel();
        mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabling Task, Please wait : " + millisUntilFinished/1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if (mToast != null) mToast.cancel();
        mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congratulations!! Time out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
    }
}.start();
```

**Warning!** This doesn't work on Android 2.3.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, Would this solve the problem of delay. Will it be able to sync with actual timing seconds ?

Comment: There's no syncing. The toast will just display what you tell it to display. And if I understand correctly a new toast will pop up every one second. It will work as you intended. Sometimes it might skip a second (only on display, the execution is still ok), so you should do some rounding on the `millisUntilFinished/1000` though.

Comment: oops, getting NullPointerException onTick

Comment: Impossible, which line?